# How can I set a column to be primary key and autoincremented in postgres from terminal?

Tags: postgresql, ddl

I want to use the following statement for creating the table `persons_table` in the `persondb` schema:

```
create table persondb.persons_table(
   id int,
   first_name varchar,
   last_name varchar,
   age int
);
```

But I want to set `id` to be a primary key and auto-increment, how to make that from bash?

I am using Postgres, and it's running in a docker container, and for the UI part I am using DBeaver.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the shell, you can call `psql` like this:

```sh
psql -U postgres -d mydatabase <<"EOF"
ALTER TABLE persondb.persons_table
   ALTER id PRIMARY KEY GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY;
EOF
```

This is called a "here document" in bash.